# Java PKCS#7 Encoding

Tags: java, криптография

Добрый день! Требуется сгенерировать подпись `PKCS#7` из строки. Хотел бы узнать ответы на несколько вопросов.

1. Для подписи по PKCS#7 необходим сертификат?
2. Если да - то каким способом можно создать подпись из строки по сертификату?

На данный момент имею файлы формата `.crt` и `.key` и никак не могу найти промер, как я могу с помощью них подписать строку. Как я понимаю из доки bouncycastle - мне необходим .jks файл (java keystore). Теперь возникает вопрос - как его сгенерировать или как я могу импортировать существующий сертификат и ключ в `.jks`.

Спасибо!

Comment: 1. само понятие «[электронная подпись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DD%EB%E5%EA%F2%F0%EE%ED%ED%E0%FF_%EF%EE%E4%EF%E8%F1%FC)» подразумевает наличие закрытого ключа (а с правовой точки зрения — «сертификата»). 2. например, [так](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718419/4827341), или, например, [так](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/15728).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что Вы хотите подписать строку и получить подпись.

1. Да, понадобится сертификат (открытый ключ и аттрибуты, идентифицирующие владельца, издателя, а также отражающие назначение сертификата) и связанный с сертификатом закрытый ключ (в зависимости от криптопровайдера может храниться в разных формах).
2. Программно. Используют:

   - http://www.bouncycastle.org/ (гибкий способ)
   - консольные вызовы openssl из java (простейший способ, нелучший)

Когда-то был пакет `sun.security.pkcs` и класс `sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7`. В документации на `Java 8` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ не нашел аналога для `security/pkcs`. Есть только описание кодировки PKCS7: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#CertPathEncodings

Comment: Таким образом, файлов .crt, .csr и .key должно быть мне достаточно для подписания строки ?

Comment: Да. Нужны crt - сертификат, key - ключ. А вот csr - запрос на сертификат - не нужен, он уже сделал свою работу, согласно нему уже создан crt-файл.

Comment: спасибо! буду курить доку